# Plotting an atan function in TikZ

Tags: pgfplots

I have to plot the function `f(x) = atan(x)-x/(1+x^2)`, but it won't come out right. By looking at previous questions, I have the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, norsk, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-10:10,
    xscale=1.5,yscale=1,
    xmin=-3, xmax=3,
    ymin=-100, ymax= 100,
    samples=1000,
    axis lines=center,
]
    \addplot+[mark=none] {atan(x) - x/(1+x^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

The code generates this graph:

[image]

but it should look like this:

[image]

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I added the screenshots for you. But you linked twice on the same picture. Please complete your code in order to make it compilable. We need your documentclass. Delete any package which is not needed in order to produce your error. Thanks. (PS: what is "tiq"?)

Comment: Thanks. I have edited it now. I don't know how you edited the images, so it is back to links.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `atan` function returns the value in degrees. You need to convert it into radians:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-10:10,
    xscale=1.5,yscale=1,
    xmin=-6, xmax=6,
    ymin=-2, ymax= 2,
    samples=1000,
    axis lines=center,
]
    \addplot+[mark=none] {rad(atan(x)) - x/(1+x^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Btw: How do you convert the pictures?

Comment: @Andreas I take a screen shot in PNG format.

Comment: @Andreas If you want to convert the pictures more programmatically, you can use `convert -density 300 myfile.pdf -trim myfile.png`. (Change `300` if you want a different resolution.) You may want to add `\pagestyle{empty}` to your TeX file to suppress page numbers. The advantages of this is that you get (a) transparent images at (b) any resolution. Here's [your graph as an example.](https://i.imgur.com/Mx5rMD1.png)