# how to write tan inverse function

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I want to write tan inverse function in my latex. I need to write tan inverse as it is and not as arctan. what is the code for that? I need to write an equation theta = tan inverse (x/y).

Comment: It is the same see: [Plotting an atan function in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208078/124842)

Comment: With `amsmath`, add `\DeclareMathOperator{\taninv}{tan\,inverse}` in the preamble and in the text use `\taninv`.

Comment: Essentially, this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/671/117534

Comment: This is just the arccotangent, no? Wouldn't `\cot^{-1}` suffice?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `amsmath`, add `\DeclareMathOperator{\taninv}{tan\,inverse}` in the preamble and in the text use `\taninv`.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\taninv}{tan\,inverse}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\theta=\taninv\frac{x}{y}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've never seen such a notation. However, if you later want to stick to more common notation, it's sufficient you change the line into

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\taninv}{arctan}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\taninv}{\tan^{-1}}
```

Comment: If I use `\DeclareMathOperator{\taninv}{tan^{-1}}`, then the `-1` bit appears as it would in text mode rather than in math mode (so it minus is a bit short, like a dash). Is there a way to fix this so the minus sign appears as it would in math mode?

Comment: @JohnDoe Ah! Another reason for not using “`tan^{-1}`”, which is also mathematically wrong. I'll fix the code.

Comment: Ahh, that's not actually the mistake I was referring to! [This](https://imgur.com/OdmWAfW) is what I mean. In the first one, I uses \taninv where \taninv is defined as \tan^{-1}. In the second one, I just wrong \tan^{-1} in the document (without defining a new operator). My question is, is there a way to replicate the second one by defining the an operator?

Comment: @JohnDoe `\tan` is an operator and remains such if you append a superscript.

Comment: Yes, I know. My document uses the syntax `\tan^{-1}` frequently, so I was looking for a way to shorten this. I actually defined `\atan` as `\tan^{-1}`, but then the `-` sign doesn't appear as it would if I just used `\tan^{-1}`. My point is, I want to avoid having to type `^{-1}` each time and would rather define a new operator, which preferably looks the same as if I had typed that.

Comment: @JohnDoe Doesn't `\newcommand{\atan}{\tan^{-1}}` do what you're looking for? With it, typing `\atan` or `\tan^{-1}` will yield the same exact result.

Comment: Ohhh yes, it does! Sorry, didn't see that change. Thanks